# LSTM multivariate Time Series Simulation

Tags: time-series, multivariate, neural-networks

I am currently working on a project involving the simulation of multivariate time series (implied-volatilities). To facilitate this process, I am seeking a GitHub repository that provides an implementation of [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) specifically designed for generating and simulating multiple underlying series over time. Thanks for any useful material!

Comment: I don't know about GitHub repositories but I would check out packages in R. There are so many packages, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a package that does what you describe.